# How to calculate the mean of a time series?

Tags: time-series

[image]

In the above image, I can intuitively know that there is a trend, so this is non-stationary time series. And existence of trend means that the mean of time series is not constant.

But in mathematically what is the mean of this time series data? How can i calculate it?

Comment: The mean is just the mean: the sum divided by the number of values. It is unlikely to be interesting, so you probably want to ask a different question. Perhaps something to do with extracting a repeating pattern from the time series. What are the data?

Comment: 1949 Jan: 112 
Feb: 118 
Mar: 132 
April:129 
May: 121 
...
1950  Jan:
Feb: 115  
...
Like this. There is only one observation at one time point. In this case, can I not calculate the mean of each time point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two main options to explore, when we want to show the mean of an existing time-series (and not extrapolate further). Either use a decomposition technique like [STL](https://otexts.com/fpp2/stl.html) where we assume the presence of both a seasonal and a smooth trend component or employ a fully non-parametric approach using a [LOESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) smoother directly where we "only smooth" our time-series data and ignore the presence of any structural components. 
In both cases, we will have an underlying mean trend. We will then be able to show this as the expect time-series mean and/or employ it as baseline for time-series bootstrap techniques (e.g. see Bergmeir et al. (2016) [Bagging exponential smoothing methods using STL decomposition and Box–Cox transformation](https://www.monash.edu/business/econometrics-and-business-statistics/research/publications/ebs/wp11-14.pdf) for a case where the STL decomposition is used for the bootstrap aggregation  of exponential smoothing methods).